# FQL, search for non-friend people and sort by mutual friends

Tags: facebook-fql

I look for facebook users (any user, not just my friends or the friends of a specific user) with a pattern in the name, like this:

```
SELECT first_name,uid FROM user WHERE contains('pete')
```

This returns an array of people who's name contains "pete" (i.e. also "peter"). The number is quite high, so the results are of course truncated. I would like to grab, in this set (before the server-side truncation) who has most mutual friends with me (or with an arbitrary user id). However, issuing

```
SELECT first_name,uid FROM user WHERE contains('pete') AND mutual_friend_count > 1
```

gives and empty set (and no errors). I think the server truncates before applying the latter selection, as in normal SQL would happen, for performance reasons (or explicit limits I missed in the documentation).

I made a second attempt by trying to retrieve all the friends of friends of a userid, and then select on the name. However, retrieving friends of friends is not allowed (and technically difficult because some friends hide their list of friends, and this breaks the query).

I can see no other way to achieve my goal... is there any? (I mean: given a userid, search for users with highest number of mutual friends).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet, since there's no FQL solution, would be to begin a database of your own following Facebook's best practices and policies of course.  That way you can structure your data.  Data can be kept current by setting up Facebook's Realtime updates API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) to capture when new friendships are made.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with "order by mutual_friend_count desc" and it worked. So the query needs to be:

> SELECT first_name,uid FROM user WHERE contains('pete') order by mutual_friend_count desc

Comment: Does not work for me. If I issue
`SELECT first_name,uid,mutual_friend_count ...`
I can also see the number of mutuals, and it is always zero or null. So, at least with my account, the set is still truncated before sorting.