# Facebook Graph API - Typeahead-like User Search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Using the search API here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1

I've noticed a big discrepancy between searching for a name using that API and searching for a name in the typeahead box at facebook.com. I imagine part of it is that the typeahead results are weighted using social relevancy like: http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2013/11/10/script-shows-facebook-ranks-friends/

I don't believe it's possible to do an API call like that, but is it possible to do an approximation? I tried ordering by mutual friends using FQL (like this question asks: [FQL, search for non-friend people and sort by mutual friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587789/fql-search-for-non-friend-people-and-sort-by-mutual-friends)) but the results seem to be too truncated.

Region/city targeting may be useful, but ideally I'd like to a way to do an accurate search without having to specify that.

Comment: There's no endpoint for a "weighted search". Simple as that. Other solutions may be approximations, but I doubt that you'll be able to produce the same results as the FB search.

Comment: Yes, I've given up on getting exactly the same results. But I just wanted to know if anyone had run into a similar problem and developed good approximations.

Comment: I understand that. Unfortunately you'll have to implement your own algorithm, or just live with the results returned by the Graph API.